# Netcat forwarding host

Tags: networking, http

This is probably pretty simple but I just can't wrap my head around it.

I set up a subdomain, let's say it's `nc.example.com`. Set up my DNS and all to point the subdomain to a remote server, which runs Nginx which reverse proxies the request to port `3123`.

Then, I listen for requests using netcat on the **remote server**, like this:

```
nc -l 3123
```

So that I can receive HTTP requests from `nc.example.com`.

Next, on my **local machine**, I use netcat to connect to an unrelated server (Google's public DNS), like this:

```
$ nc 8.8.8.8 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: nc.example.com
```

(with extra 2 newlines so that it completes the HTTP request, but can't be displayed here)

I receive the connection on my **remote server** as follows:

```
$ nc -l 3123
GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection: upgrade
Host: nc.example.com
X-Real-IP: <redacted_1>
X-Forwarded-Host: nc.example.com
X-Forwarded-Server: nc.example.com
X-Forwarded-For: <redacted_2>, <redacted_1>
```

Now, I'm not sure why this happens, because I thought that `nc` will connect to `8.8.8.8`, rather than my server's IP address. Is `8.8.8.8` forwarding the request to my server on my behalf? Are there any security implications as a result of this?

---

**EDIT**:

I just realised that `<redacted_2>` is a private IP address (`172.24.199.96`) assigned to my "home" network (accessing it brings me to my router's homepage). I am doing this within my college's network.

Does this mean that the upstream router is proxying the request for me, based on the `Host` header? It's understandable because my college recently implemented some sort of network filtering though there's not much details about it. Though I don't understand why it behaves this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What IP address does your Nginx server receive the connection *from*?

It looks like there is a "transparent proxy" intercepting all HTTP requests that your local computer sends, and forwarding them based on the Host header. (Might be a virus, an antivirus, a caching proxy, a parental filter, etc.)

Especially because your X-Forwarded-For header has two IP addresses, even though Nginx should only have added one.

The Google DNS servers certainly don't perform such forwarding – they do not even accept connections on port 80. (In fact, "open proxies" behaving like that would be widely considered a security problem...)

Comment: You're right, I tried to connect to the same server from a different machine and it didn't work. I edited the question to add additional details, I realised that `redacted_2` is a private IP address. My upstream router is probably doing the proxying, but why would it forward requests based on the `Host` header?

Comment: That's how "transparent" proxies work. The firewall quietly redirects all TCP:80 connections to the proxy, at which point the 'original' destination IP is lost. So the proxy must guess the real destination based on the HTTP request itself. /// As for _why_ your router is doing the proxying… that's a question for its owners/administrators.

Comment: Thanks, I actually just figured that out as well. There's probably some filtering and caching going on, since it's a university network.